# How can I optimize the Manipulate function in plotting?

Tags: plotting, functions, performance-tuning, manipulate, dynamic

Ahoy! I'm trying to create a Fourier series visualization tool that allows me to interactively view a Fourier series as a function of the number of terms using `Manipulate`, but every time I run it, Mathematica becomes crazy slow and in most cases aborts the cell automatically. Here is the command I'm using right now:

```
f = \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(n = 1\), \(m\)]\(
\*FractionBox[\(4\), \(n*\[Pi]\)] \((Sin[
\*FractionBox[\(\[Pi]*n\), \(2\)]]*Cos[n*t])\)\)\);

Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[Table[f, {m, b}]], {t, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Thickness[.002]}], {b, 1, 10}]
```

It seems to work okay for small upper bounds of `b` ($ \leq 8$), but beyond that I have problems.

Also, the first block of code that defines the function is input text for Mathematica. It says this: $$f=\sum _{n=1}^m \frac{4 \left(\sin \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}\right) \cos (n t)\right)}{\pi  n}$$ Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the plots as they are generated and reuse them.

```
ClearAll[f];
mem : f[m_] := mem = Plot[
    Evaluate@Sum[(4/(n*Pi))*(Sin[(Pi*n)/2]*Cos[n*t]), {n, 1, m}],
    {t, -2*Pi, 2*Pi},
    PlotStyle -> {Thickness[.002], ColorData[97][m]}];

Manipulate[
 Show[Table[f[m], {m, b}]],
 {{b, 1, "b"}, 1, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {b}]
```

Answer (score 1):

try to see if this is faster

```
f[m_, t_] := Sum[(4/(n*Pi))*(Sin[(Pi*n)/2]*Cos[n*t]), {n, 1, m}]; 

Manipulate[Plot[Evaluate[Table[f[m, t], {m, b}], {t, -2*Pi, 2*Pi}], 
  PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.002]}], 
   {{b, 1, "b"}, 1, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 ContinuousAction -> False,
 TrackedSymbols :> {b}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]